# uuid v5 in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

Does Postgres (or a Postgres extension) have a uuid v5 function (ie one that takes in a UUID name space and a string to produce a new UUID)?

If not a native function, how would one write this function?

Comment: How is UUID v5 defined?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) module provides such function.

> uuid_generate_v5(namespace uuid, name text)
>
> This function generates a version 5 UUID, which works like a version 3 UUID except that SHA-1 is used as a hashing method. Version 5 should be preferred over version 3 because SHA-1 is thought to be more secure than MD5.